# Left Regular Representations of a Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

The definition in my book gives it as $\lambda_x$ such that $\lambda_xg=xg$.I understand this much. But my question asks to find the left regular representation of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ in $S_3$.

I don't undertand how to do this at all. If we are working under addition, it doesn't matter whether or not we add from the left or right, correct? I am missing how to connect this to permutations. Any tips/advice would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any finite group $G$ you can view the left regular representation as a homomorphism $G \rightarrow S_{|G|} \cong Sym(G)$, since left multiplication just permutes group elements.

Therefore, taking $1 \in \mathbb{Z}_3$ ($0$ of course acts as the identity and is rather uninteresting), we have:

\begin{align*}\lambda_1 0 = 1+0=1\\
\lambda_1 1 = 1+1=2\\
\lambda_1 2 = 1+2 =0\end{align*}

So, the action of $1$ on $Sym(G)$ is given by $(0,1,2)$. Can you see how this would generalise for $\lambda_2$/what subgroup of $S_3$ this generates? Hint: it's quite similar to what you began with...

As for the right/left distinction, in this case it doesn't matter since the group is abelian. The left regular representation corresponds to rows (or columns, I can never remember) of the Cayley table, and the right corresponds to columns (or rows). They are of course isomorphic in general, but the distinction is important, since we can get different permutations in $Sym(G)$ by taking the left/right action respectively.

Comment: Then wouldn't the right regular representation be the same? Lets take $2\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then we would have $$ 2+0=2$$ $$2+1=0$$ $$2+2=1$$ Giving $(021)$?

Comment: Yes, when the group is abelian they are exactly the same, but in general they are equivalent/isomorphic (perhaps a nice exercise to show). Indeed for $2$. What subgroup of $S_3$ have you found?

Comment: So we have $\{e, (012), (021)\}$. Now, does this mean this is our "left regular representation"?

Comment: Yep! Hence the left regular representation has image isomorphic to...?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_3$? I think I am wrong in this. But my question asks to find the subgroup of $S_n$ this is isomorphic to.

Comment: No, you are correct! Any $3$-cycle, $\sigma$ in $S_n$ generates a cyclic subgroup $\langle \sigma \rangle \cong C_3 (\cong \mathbb{Z}_3)$. In more generality, for $k\leq n$, a $k$-cycle in $S_n$ generates a cyclic subgroup isomorphic to $C_k$.

Comment: I am a bit confused. It asks "identify the subgroup of $S_n$ isomorphic to it." Are we saying $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is a subgroup of $S_3$? That does not make sense to me for some reason.

Comment: It is isomorphic to the subgroup generated by a $3$-cycle yes. That doesn't mean the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ lie inside $S_n$ though. Are you happy with the fact that we can identify the left regular representation with the permutations $\{id, (0,1,2) , (0,2,1)\}$ in $S_3$?

Comment: Sort of. I understand that we have those three permutations in $S_3$ by what we did with the $\lambda_i$ $i\in\{0,1,2\}$ I don't know where that method came from though. I guess it's because a permutation is a function that takes one thing to another thing. If we add the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ to itself, we would get exactly those 3 permutations.

Comment: Okay, are you happy with how each $\lambda_i$ can be viewed as an element of $Sym(\mathbb{Z}_3)$ and why we can identify $Sym(\mathbb{Z}_3)$ with $S_3$? If you think about how the left regular representation is defined, it gives for each group element a bijection $G \rightarrow G$, and thus can be thought of as a permutation on the set $G$. This is where this identification arises from. It might help to read up a bit more on group actions, as this is essentially all we're dealing with here.

Comment: I will keep reading up on this and try to understand it better. Thank you very much for your help. I'll ask my professor tomorrow about it as well. I don't want to just memorize the method but to understand the process.

Comment: Indeed, the understanding is of course what's key. If you want another example, we can look at the Klein 4 group, $G=C_2 \times C_2 = \{e,a,b,ab\}$, then we have $G^e=id$, $G^a = (e,a)(b,ab)$, $G^b = (e,b)(a,ab)$, $G^{ab} = (e,ab)(a,b)$. ($G^x$ denotes the permutation $g \mapsto x\cdot g$ on $G$). You should hopefully be to see that this generates a subgroup of $Sym(C_2 \times C_2) \cong S_4$ isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$ - see a pattern emerging?

Comment: I just worked out $\mathbb{Z}_5$. It seems as if whenever you use $\mathbb{Z}_n$ in $S_n$, then $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is isomorphic to $S_n$ for each $n$. The "set" we found by finding the left regular representation, is this considered $S_3$? Wait a minute… What we did to $\mathbb{Z}_3$ showed by definition that $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is isomorphic to $S_3$ didn't it?

Comment: Be careful! $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is certainly not isomorphic to $S_n$ (unless $n\leq2$). The regular representation generates a **proper** subgroup of $S_n$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: So the proper subgroup generated by the left regular representation is a subgroup of $S_3$ and this proper subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Comment: Bingo! It's probably a good idea to try some more complex examples, perhaps with groups that aren't cyclic so that you can really get a handle on the explicit permutations in $Sym(G)$. What this is really getting at is that every group of order $n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking your time to help me understand this clearly. I'm actually working on the last problem of this kind working with $2\times 2$ diagonal matrices with diagonals either 1 or -1

Comment: In this case, we are using multiplication, does this mean we take the 4 elements in this "set" and multiply each one by the other 3 matrices?

Comment: Precisely, and write the corresponding permutations down :)

Comment: How would we order these 4 matrices? They don't really "get bigger" per se like the cyclic group 3

Comment: Write $G = \{g_1 , g_2, g_3,g_4\}$. Then your permutations are cycles of the form $(g_i, g_j , \ldots)$.

Comment: The matrix we define to be $g_i$ does not change the answer if we define them differently, does it?

Comment: No, as long as you are consistent! (Though for style, I would probably define $g_1 = I_2$.)

Comment: Yup, $g_1$ is the identity and then $g_4$ is the negative identity.

Comment: I got $$\{e, (g_1g_2)(g_3g_4), (g_1g_3)(g_2g_4), (g_1g_4)(g_2g_3)\}$$

Comment: I agree. Again, this is isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2 \leq Sym(g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4)$. If you look at the matrices, you should see why: the multiplication occurs entrywise along the diagonal, and we essentially have a direct product of two matrix blocks - the top left hand corner is $C_2$, generated by $-1$ under multiplication, and the same for the bottom right corner. (If you have any other questions, I'm off to bed now so hopefully someone else can pick up...!)

Comment: Right, therefore the subgroup of $S_4$ generated by the left regular representation of the diagonal matrices $2\times2$ with diagonal 1 or -1 is isomorphic to $G_2\times G_2$.